# Time taken for function loading in C#

Tags: c#

I am using microsoft analyzer tool for performance analysis.
I find that in C# time taken to load a method is more than time for execution . Function load time is depending upon the number of lines of code in that method
Please Replay as soon as possible

Answer (score 4):

.NET uses JIT (Just In Time) to turn the IL to assembly on first access, therefore the first time a function is called takes longer than the following times.

Comment: For the record: The ANTS profiler also displays this time as "JIT overhead".

Comment: Make sure you are profiling at the appropriate level and under the appropriate use scenario. It's the overall bottlenecks that are usually important and not times of individual method invocations (of course this depends on the frequency of method invocation as well). If it's not a dominant factor, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You may precompile the code on the target machine using [Ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx). The same technique is used if you place an assembly in the global assembly cache (GAC).

This might speed up your code.

Comment: Questionable promise detected.

Comment: That's not questionable...I worked on a project which runs on a terminal server. Users complained about timeouts and long loading times when launching the application. Running Ngen on some of the libraries speeded up the whole loading time to a few seconds

Comment: It might speed up the program, and it might not. Saying it should provide a speedup is questionable.

Comment: Ok...I changed it to "might"...(English is not my native language)

Comment: Are you sure (all) assemblies in the GAC are Ngenned? I don't think this is the case.

Comment: +1 Adding assemblies to the GAC saves the JIT compilation time - it is done in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I find that in C# time taken to load a method is more than time for execution .

What is the method?

> Function load time is depending upon the number of lines of code in that method

Sounds reasonable.

What is the problem? If whatever your project is depends on performance at this low of a level managed code is not the right choice for you. Try C and ASM.